# is different data types like string int and array in the same csv file can be readable in java?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, data-structures

[image]

this is the model to follow for the assignment.
I have created java classes as you can see down below.

```java
class BookerPrize{
        
        private int year;
        book winner;
        List<book> shortlist;
        List<String> panel;
        String chairPerson;
        public BookerPrize( int year,book winner, List<book> shortlist, List<String> panel, String chairPerson) {
                super();
                this.winner = winner;
                this.shortlist = shortlist;
                this.panel = panel;
                this.year = year;
                this.chairPerson = chairPerson;
        }
        public book getwinner() {
                return winner;
        }
        public List<book> getshortlist() {
                return shortlist;
        }
        public List<String> getpanel() {
                return panel;
        }
        public int getYear() {
                return year;
        }
        public String getchairPerson() {
                return chairPerson;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
           
                return "Winner : " + " [ " + winner.getTitle() + "  " + winner.getTitle() + "  " + winner.getTitle() + " ] " + "\n" + "year : " + year + "\n" + "chair man : " + chairPerson + "\n";
        }
        
}
```

and here is the book.java class

```java
public class book {
     private String title,author,publisher;
       
        public book(String title, String author, String publisher) {
               
                this.title = title;
                this.author = author;
                this.publisher = publisher;
             
        }
        public String getTitle() {
                return title;
        }
        public String getauthor() {
                return author;
        }
        public String getpublisher() {
                return publisher;
        }
      
}
```

I am a little confused about how can I make get data from CSV to this pattern.
I have created a dummy dataset that I believe could be suitable for this task. here you can see

int year, book `[title.......,author..,publishers], List<book> [[title.......,author..,publishers],[title.......,author..,publishers],.....], List<String> [panelmember1,panelmember2,panelmember3,.....panelmember(n)], String chairperson`
///////////////////////////////multiple entries as above//////////////////////////////////

**Tell me if I am doing right ? ... I have tried to scan this .txt file through the scanner but this wasn't helpful because I was trying to split the line through "," but can be able to get book class parameters. let me know how can I get these parameters in java.**

Here is the complete question of the problem u can check

> You are required to write a Java 8 program that opens and reads a
> delimited data file that is located relative to the NetBeans project
> root folder. The delimited data file contains information about Booker
> prize winning and shortlisted novels. The data file is called
> booker-data.txt. The data file must not be altered and should be
> considered as a read-only data file.
>
> The data file is delimited in a consistent structure and contains
> entries relating to 20 years of Booker prize winners and shortlisted
> nominees. Each entry contains a series of data fields representing the
> following information: the year of the prize, the winning author, the
> winning book title, the authors and book titles of shortlisted
> nominees, the panel members who were responsible for deciding the
> winner, and an indication of which panel member acted as chairperson.
> You are required to implement Java classes to represent the Booker
> prize winning information with respect to this data set. The program
> should parse the data file and create and store a collection of
> objects for each entity.
>
> Figure 3 provides a partial UML class representation of the classes
> that you will need to implement. It illustrates a core class to
> represent the Booker prize information alongside a utility class to
> represent the basic details of a book. The class model indicates the
> data members and accessor (i.e., getter) methods that map to those
> data members, and a toString() method for the BookerPrize class. It is
> left to you to determine how the objects should be initialised. Once
> all the objects are loaded into the collection, the program should
> present the User with a console-based menu to interact with the data
> set.
>
> This menu should loop until the User enters a character to exit the
> menu (e.g., zero as illustrated below). In addition to an exit option,
> the menu should offer three other options: list, select and search. On
> starting the program, the following menu should be displayed to the
> console:
>
> ```
> ---------------------- Booker prize menu
> ---------------------- List ................1 Select ..............2 Search ..............3 Exit.................0
> ---------------------- Enter choice:>
> ```
>
> The User can simply exit the program by entering zero. The three other
> menu options allow the User to inspect the information in the data set
> (note again that this program is entirely read-only and there is no
> requirement to add, update or delete any part of the data set). The
> necessary interaction of the program with respect to these options is
> illustrated in Appendix A.
>
> Note that console output should be neatly formatted, and some
> consideration will be given to formatting when the program is
> assessed. In particular, when the option to view the details of the
> Booker prize winner and shortlist for a given year is selected (i.e.,
> the ‘select’ menu option), it must result in the invocation of the
> toString() method for that particular BookerPrize object. You are
> required to utilise a StringBuilder object when implementing the
> toString() method for the BookerPrize class.

Comment: *I have tried to scan this .txt file through the scanner* - no use a csv reader class

Comment: Class names should start with uppercase in Java conventions: `Book`, not `book`.

Comment: Minor tip: [records](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395). Write classes more briefly. Example, reduce your entire `Book` class to `public record Book ( String title, String author, String publisher ) {}`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for an algorithm to (1) parse CSV files and (2) convert text to a Java objects.

For (1) you can use a CSV parsing library like opencsv, check out this guide: https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/ . For (2) you can use a deserialization library like jackson, check out this guide: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization.

When you use a java.io.Scanner to read file contents the library is reading each line and converting it into a String object (string of text). So, if you want to solve (2) yourself, you will need to first define a format on how you want to write each structure (e.g., arrays) and then create an algorithm to convert it into a Java structure (e.g., java.util.ArrayList). For example, let's say you define the format for arrays to be delimited by | (e.g., a|b|c), then you can write a function to convert this to a list and use this function as part of your program.

```
List toList(String csvColumnStr) {
   return Arrays.asList(csvColumnStr.split('|'))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSV is intended for [flat tabular data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat-file_database).

You want more.

In a quoted field you could have again comma separated text, which you could parse in a second step. A `List<string>` for instance.

For a `List<Book>` (please capitalize class names) there exists an other technique:
using different record types, placing in an additional first field the record type:

```
BookerPrize ... ... ...
Book ... ...
Book ... ...
BookerPrize ... ... ...
Book ... ...
Book ... ...
```

However all this is very circumstantial.

Some probably would advise to use the hierarchical [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format.

I am more the friend of [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), which has a validated syntax, so dangerous typos are easily found, and you can use java with [*Jakarta XML Binding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_XML_Binding) (formerly *JAXB*, *Java Architecture for XML Binding*) annotations to read and write Java objects. Quite easy. Also the types do not need hand-made conversion.

Comment: @BasilBourque The edit is quite worthwile, especially remembering the somewhat painfull transition from java JAXB to jakarta in modular java.